# Add subscriber to automation multiple times in MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I've a MailChimp Automation for an custom e-commerce. I want to use my MailChimp Automation Workflow to send information to customers when they have placed an order. Overview:

1. Send order information
2. Send mail #2 after 2 days

**This works great, but here comes the problem!**
The user (with the same email) creates one more order 1 month later. I now want this customer to be placed in the automation again, but instead I get an error "You've already sent this email to the subscriber.". I'm using MailChimp API v.3.

How can I possibly add this customer to the same automation workflow again?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done. We ended up using Mandrill instead. Hope this helps!